# Can't refer to an Entry field inside a class?

Tags: python, tkinter, nameerror, tkinter-entry

I'm trying to set a global variable to the value entered into a Tkinter Entry field, but I'm getting the following error:

> NameError: global name 'HealthEntry' is not defined

Here's the relevant code:

```
Health = 0

class window(Tk):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent

        HealthEntry = Entry(self)

        testButton = Button(self, text = "entry field test", command = self.printHealth)
        testButton.grid(row=18, column=3)

    def printHealth(self):
        Health = HealthEntry.get()
        print Health
```

I've also tried changing HealthEntry.get() to window.HealthEntry.get(), but that doesn't work either. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Because your `HealthEntry` is not defined with self so basically he is locally to `__init__` method.

change it to: `self.HealthEntry`

```
def __init__(self, parent):
        Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent

        self.HealthEntry = Entry(self)

        testButton = Button(self, text = "entry field test", command = self.printHealth)
        testButton.grid(row=18, column=3)

def printHealth(self):
    Health = self.HealthEntry.get()
    print Health
```

As Padraic wrote in his answer, you might want to use testButton as a class member as well..

Comment: then he also needs to refer to it properly in the `printHealth` method

Answer (score 1):

Make it an actual attribute and use `self.HealthEntry`, you might also want to do the same for  testButton `self.testButton`:

```
        self.HealthEntry = Entry()    
        self.testButton = Button(self, text = "entry field test", command = self.printHealth)
        self.testButton.grid(row=18, column=3)

    def printHealth(self):
        Health = self.HealthEntry.get()
        print Health
```

To make it global and accessible outside the init method you would need to use the global keyword in the init method `global HealthEntry` but the correct way is to make it an attribute as above.